# How can I hide spam emails in my inbox of OSX Apple Mail app?

Tags: macos, iphone, mail.app, spam

I label my emails as spam or better *"Junk email"* in my iPhone and MacBook Air but the emails continue to stay in my inbox. I want to get rid of them without removing them so I can later improve my spam filtering with SpamAssistant in my server. How can I hide spam emails in my inbox of OSX Apple Mail app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether the OXS settings will propagate somehow to iPhone. Anyway I could find the following settings in OSX.

**Preferences > Accounts > Mailbox Behaviors**

[image]

**Preferences > Junk Mail**

[image]

Comment: This will be seen on all clients using IMAP tahnks to your right setting of `Store junk messages on the server`. Please add a red circle around this key option.  Please add a red circle around the wining point of your answer: `Move it to the Junk mailbox` :).